# Unable to receive mail in local server from external server with MX record

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, email-server, dovecot, imap

I am not being able to receive mails in my local accounts, i can only send mails from multi local accounts (@remote.A) to multi external accounts (@A). I can send to every domain (e.g. gmail).

Till now after several tests, i notice that when i send mails without SMTP AUTH, i receive a message from my ISP mail server, saying that SMTP AUTH is activated and i must activated to pass through that server. If i try to send mail in the external server between accounts of my domain, i dont receive any mail in my local server. If i try to send mail in my local server between local accounts, i will receive mail locally, it will not pass through my external server as expected.

In my external server, i have cpanel, where i create external email accounts. There i have config email routing for the domain that i just want to use in my local mail server. I have set MX records with a secondary priority (in first i have the domain of my email by default). It is config as auto to deal with mail brought also by default(*). The secondary priority is a link (a subdomain of the email domain) for my static IP. I already search if i had my IP blocked and from a big list i only had 1 blocking me.
I have also configured SPF of my external server to auth sends from my local server.

(*)

Automatically Detect Configuration : (Local)
Mail Exchanger local
Mail Exchanger de backup
Mail Exchanger remote

Right now i have in my main.cf from local server Postfix this:
http://pastebin.com/KsEDzD4T

I have been trying to reroute received external mails to local accounts in my local server through virtual_alias_maps but i think thats not the problem right now, since i am unable to push mail from the external server. Received mail are being stack in that server.

Since i am testing in DMZ all ports are open. Then i look for a local firewall, and is off by default.

But i have process's running at least for IMAP (SMTP and POP3 i have non):

```
remote:Postfix root# netstat -tnlp tcp | grep '\.143 '
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.1.143        192.168.1.1.50825      ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.1.50825      192.168.1.1.143        ESTABLISHED
remote:Postfix root# netstat -tnlp tcp | grep '\.993 '
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.1.993        192.168.1.1.49455      ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.1.49455      192.168.1.1.993        ESTABLISHED
tcp4     143      0  192.168.1.1.65235      192.168.1.1.993        CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.1.993        192.168.1.1.54435      ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.1.54435      192.168.1.1.993        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.1.993        192.168.1.1.50955      ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.1.50955      192.168.1.1.993        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.1.993        192.168.1.1.50944      ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.1.50944      192.168.1.1.993        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.1.993        192.168.1.1.50874      ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.1.50874      192.168.1.1.993        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.1.993        192.168.1.1.50852      ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.1.50852      192.168.1.1.993        ESTABLISHED
```

I dont know well for what ports mail will be pushed from external server to local, since it is a connection from an MTA to a MTA i think.

The external IP address that i am using now for testing is a dynamic IP with a DNS name with DNS reverse possible activated. I will add a static IP after set this mail server.

SPF RAW:
v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:X ~all

I think that i have made the correct steps with cpanel, but i dont have a clue on how can i set Postfix and Dovecot to receive/push mails from my external server. This is my first time trying to do this and i need some expert advise.

Answer (score 1):

In order to receive mail you must have SMTP open and enabled. That's how other servers deliver mail to your server. IMAP and POP3 are only for reading email remotely. You should be able to use SMTP to send mail between mailboxes on your domain, as well as send mail from outside addresses to your domain. Be careful not to enable an "open relay" that will send to and from an outside address.

Try and connect to your server with telnet and get a more detailed error.

```
telnet smtp.example.com 25
```

Follow [this guide](http://www.anta.net/misc/telnet-troubleshooting/smtp.shtml) on sending email using telnet and look for the specific error codes that the smtp server returns. You can also look at the mail queue `mailq | less` which will show messages that are awaiting delivery and if they have tried to delver them yet.

Comment: But i can send and receive well internally (i have test in localhost through SMTP and IMAP ports :: http://prntscr.com/d4nic9), and i can also send to outside domains, i am using SMTP auths individually per user. I can do telnet at local host but i am unable to telnet from external IP, i get connection refuse. But all my firewalls are disable. =/

Comment: I forgot to say about awaiting delivery command, thanks for it! I have that queue empty. I am not able to retrieve a SMTP error because my problem is about incoming mail from a cpanel server. After testing i notice that i was using the wrong DNS name (one that is not pointing directly to my server), so using the right one with port forwarding i was able to connect to port 25. During that period of time i have not received any mail at my local user accounts. It could be from ISP IP provider? because its a dynamic IP? i have check this IP for blacklist and got only 1 blocking me from a big list.

Comment: Some ISPs block port 25, if your server is at home it may not work. Try telnet YOUR_SERVER_IP 25 and see if it will connect, if ports are forwarded and firewall is open call your isp.

Comment: thanks ca.adamgordon i have done a workaround with Getmail.